# How to add objects to a 2D Array based on characters in an input file using Java Stream

Tags: java, arrays, oop, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading inputs from a file where each line has equal number of characters.

```
o o t o o o o o o o

o o o o o o o T o o

r r r o o o o T o o

r r r r o o o o o o

r r r r r t o o o o
```

I'm trying to add objects to a 2D array of type Square[ ][ ]. 
Square is an interface with multiple implementations like SquareOne, SquareTwo, SquareThree etc.

Wherever the file has 'o', I intend to add a SquareOne object for that location. Likewise SquareTwo for 't' , SquareThree for 'r' and so on.
For example square[0][0] should have SquareOne obj while [0][2] should have SquareTwo obj.

How can I achieve it using java 8 stream?

I've come as far as reading characters of this file and adding them all to a char[][] Array. But instead, I want to add objects based on the character to Square[ ][ ].

```
 public static char[][] addFromFileToSquareArray(String filePath){
        char[][] doubleChar = new char[5][10];
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
           doubleChar =  stream
                         .map(x->x.replaceAll(" ",""))
                         .map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doubleChar;
    }
```

Comment: So… just do it? `map` to your desired objects instead of mapping char arrays…

Comment: but it has to be according to each character in the file. Am i missing something blatantly basic?

Comment: The actual operation? You are doing now `.map(x->x.replaceAll(" ","").toCharArray())` (just scattered between two `map` calls) and want to replace it by an operation that converts the `String` into an array of your objects instead. Basically, you already know how to do it. You just have to do it again: `.map(line -> line.chars().mapToObj(ch -> get/construct your object).toArray(YourObject[]::new))`. It’s not different than your outer operation `stream.map( above logic ).toArray(YourObject[][]::new)`

Comment: In this where does it check what type of character it is? objects have to be created accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to stream over the characters of each string, like

```
public static Square[][] addFromFileToSquareArray(String filePath) {
    Square[][] squares;
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        squares = stream
            .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
            .map(line -> line.chars()
                .filter(ch -> ch != ' ')
                .mapToObj(ch -> ch =='o'? new SquareOne():
                          ch == 't'? new SquareTwo(): new SquareThree())
                .toArray(Square[]::new) )
            .toArray(Square[][]::new);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return squares;
}
```

Generally, I’d prefer to declare `throws IOException` at the method to enforce the caller to deal with potential exceptions reasonably. At least, you should not catch excpeptions, just to print them and return a result value that will cause other problems at a later time (like an uninitialized array like in your original code).

Since the mapping seems to be intended to be extensible, it’s worth moving it into a method of its own, e.g.

```
public static Square squareFor(int type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'o': return new SquareOne();
        case 't': return new SquareTwo();
        case 'r': return new SquareThree();
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("type "+(char)type);
    }
}
```

and use

```
public static Square[][] addFromFileToSquareArray(String filePath) {
    Square[][] squares;
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        squares = stream
            .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
            .map(line -> line.chars()
                .filter(ch -> ch != ' ')
                .mapToObj(Square::squareFor)
                .toArray(Square[]::new) )
            .toArray(Square[][]::new);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return squares;
}
```

<sup>I placed the `squareFor` method right in the `Square` interface. Otherwise, you have to change the class in the `Square::squareFor` reference.</sup>

Alternatively, you could use a `Map`

```
public static Square[][] addFromFileToSquareArray(String filePath) {
    Square[][] squares;
    Pattern spaces = Pattern.compile(" ");
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        squares = stream
            .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
            .map(line -> spaces.splitAsStream(line)
                .map(Square::squareFor)
                .toArray(Square[]::new) )
            .toArray(Square[][]::new);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return squares;
}
static final Map<String,Supplier<Square>> MAP = Map.of(
    "o", SquareOne::new,
    "t", SquareTwo::new,
    "r", SquareThree::new
);
public static Square squareFor(String type) {
    Supplier<Square> s = MAP.get(type);
    if(s == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("type "+type);
    return s.get();
}
```

Here, the line gets split into substrings uses the spaces as delimiter, which will intrinsically eliminate them, so there’s no `filter` operation needed afterwards. But your life would be much easier if you could redefine your input format to not contain these spaces.

Comment: When we omit `.toArray(Square[]::new)` it throws `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` Why that is happening?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala When you omit the terminal operation of the Stream, you are mapping to a `Stream` instance. Of course, you can’t store a `Stream<Square>` into a `Square[][]` array.

Comment: @Holger: Thank you for the detailed answer. It's showing a
 "Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert Square[ ][ ] to A[ ]"  at first .Array(Square[ ]::new)  and
 "Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert Square[ ][ ] to Square[ ][ ]"  at second .Array(Square[ ][ ]::new) function in your first approach.

Comment: Please check whether you’ve used the code exactly as posted and that all brackets are correct. The method is `toArray` not `Array`. Also it’s rather strange to see a message containing `Square[ ][ ]` at `toArray(Square[ ]::new)` where this type is not used.

Comment: Typo int the comment above at *.toArray and "Square*[ ] to A[ ]". 
I copied the exact function above. Even tried changing Square to a parent class instead of interface but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Works perfectly now. It's bizarre, my package name was the same as interface name. After I changed it, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot again ! Some key learnings from your answer.